# Is there a way to check whether a font-family is rendering, other than simply eyeballing it?

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

Inspect Element shows the correct combination of font-families, but there's one in particular that I want to make sure is rendering. (The visual differences between having it and not having it are practically indiscernible, but I need to do it as a work assignment regardless.)

Comment: In chrome, open the debugger, go to computed, at the bottom is "Rendered Fonts".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I do that very often. Let's say you have `font-family: Georgia, Arial, "Comic Sans MS";` When the inspector is open, simply change the name by typing something in the font name, `Geo2rgia`, the next one `Arial` will become active, and so on. You'll see the font is being changed dynamically on the webpage.